# docker-compose fails to up container, yet docker run by hand succeeds

Tags: docker, flask, docker-compose

I'm having a problem with docker-compose bringing up my container. But when I run the container by hand, it works. This project is a test flask blog which I'm using to learn both flask and dockerizing it. In addition, I'm trying to get the uwsgi component of the flask container to reload without having to relaunch the container. If I can succeed with that, I can modify the flask blog code on the filesystem, trigger uwsgi reload, and see the results in browser right away. This setup requires a docker volume. So, here we go with the details:

docker-compose up should bring up 2 containers: nginx and flask. nginx succeeds, flask fails with this:

```
flask    | realpath() of flaskblog/uwsgi.ini failed: No such file or directory [core/utils.c line 3662]
flask exited with code 1
```

But, that file `flaskblog/uwsgi.ini` is in fact present in the container. Here are details of the layout and me running that failed flask container, then running uwsgi by hand. (Btw, it was a pain, a journey in itself to get docker-compose to handle the project's file layout. More journey to come on project layouts I'm sure..)

```
[wintermute]$ tree -L 2 --gitignore
.
├── app.py
├── docker-compose.yml
├── flaskblog
│   ├── config.py
│   ├── dev
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── errors
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── instance
│   ├── logging_test.py
│   ├── main
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── posts
│   ├── static
│   ├── templates
│   ├── users
│   └── uwsgi.ini
├── instance
│   ├── site.db
├── nginx
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── nginx.conf
└── requirements.txt


[wintermute]$ cat flaskblog/Dockerfile
FROM python:3.11
ENV LANG=C.UTF-8
WORKDIR /app
COPY app.py requirements.txt /app
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install itsdangerous==2.0.1
WORKDIR /app/flaskblog
COPY flaskblog/ /app/flaskblog/
WORKDIR /app/instance
COPY instance/site.db /app/instance
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8003
CMD [ "uwsgi", "flaskblog/uwsgi.ini" ]
```

That last, repeated `WORKDIR /app` feels weird and wrong, but that made it work when I run by hand...

```
[wintermute]$ cat nginx/Dockerfile
FROM nginx:latest
ENV LANG=C.UTF-8
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
EXPOSE 8083

[wintermute]$ cat docker-compose.yml
version: '3.7'
services:
  flask:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./flaskblog/Dockerfile
    container_name: flask
    restart: "no"
    environment:
      - APP_NAME=MyFlaskApp
    expose:
      [ 8003 ]
    cap_add:
        - SYS_PTRACE
    volumes:
      - ./flaskblog:/app

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    container_name: nginx
    restart: "no"
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    cap_add:
        - SYS_PTRACE


[wintermute]$ docker-compose up
Creating nginx ... done
Creating flask ... done
Attaching to flask, nginx
nginx    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
nginx    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
flask    | realpath() of flaskblog/uwsgi.ini failed: No such file or directory [core/utils.c line 3662]
nginx    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
nginx    | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf is not a file or does not exist
nginx    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Sourcing /docker-entrypoint.d/15-local-resolvers.envsh
nginx    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
nginx    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
nginx    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
nginx    | 2023/10/13 23:42:23 [notice] 1#1: using the "epoll" event method
nginx    | 2023/10/13 23:42:23 [notice] 1#1: nginx/1.25.2
nginx    | 2023/10/13 23:42:23 [notice] 1#1: built by gcc 12.2.0 (Debian 12.2.0-14)
nginx    | 2023/10/13 23:42:23 [notice] 1#1: OS: Linux 5.15.0-86-generic
nginx    | 2023/10/13 23:42:23 [notice] 1#1: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
nginx    | 2023/10/13 23:42:23 [notice] 1#1: start worker processes
nginx    | 2023/10/13 23:42:23 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 20
nginx    | 2023/10/13 23:42:23 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 21
nginx    | 2023/10/13 23:42:23 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 22
nginx    | 2023/10/13 23:42:23 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 23
flask exited with code 1


[wintermute]$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE             COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS                     PORTS                                               NAMES
4c6a69f4ab70   flaskblog_flask   "uwsgi flaskblog/uws…"   6 minutes ago   Exited (1) 6 minutes ago                                                       flask
86b1ee5367d7   flaskblog_nginx   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   6 minutes ago   Up 6 minutes               80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8083->8083/tcp, :::8083->8083/tcp   nginx
```

As you can see, the flask container failed. Now here's the demo of me running the container by hand, demonstrating the files are in fact in place, and start it up:

```
[wintermute]$ docker rm 4c6a69f4ab70
4c6a69f4ab70

[wintermute]$ docker container run -it --name flask --network flaskblog_default flaskblog_flask sh
# /bin/bash
root@91984e3f5c0e:/app# ls -l
total 16
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  119 Oct 10 00:22 app.py
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Oct 10 00:34 flaskblog
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Oct 10 00:35 instance
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  428 Oct 10 00:32 requirements.txt
root@91984e3f5c0e:/app# ls -l flaskblog/
total 60
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  455 Oct 10 00:34 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1118 Sep  9 06:39 __init__.py
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct 10 00:33 __pycache__
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1356 Sep  9 06:39 config.py
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Sep  8 23:38 dev
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Sep  8 23:38 errors
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct  9 08:52 instance
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1686 Aug 26 23:44 logging_test.py
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Sep  8 23:38 main
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2088 Sep  9 23:27 models.py
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Sep  5 08:10 posts
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Aug 29 05:44 static
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Sep  8 23:38 templates
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Oct 10 00:33 users
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  188 Oct 10 00:22 uwsgi.ini

root@91984e3f5c0e:/app# cat flaskblog/uwsgi.ini
[uwsgi]
# ?? module = wsgi:app
wsgi-file = app.py
callable = app
socket = 0.0.0.0:8003
processes = 4
threads = 2
master = true
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
touch-reload = /app/flaskblog/uwsgi.ini

root@91984e3f5c0e:/app# uwsgi flaskblog/uwsgi.ini
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from flaskblog/uwsgi.ini
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.22 (64bit) on [Fri Oct 13 23:54:18 2023] ***
[...snip]
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 29)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 30, cores: 2)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 32, cores: 2)
spawned uWSGI worker 3 (pid: 34, cores: 2)
spawned uWSGI worker 4 (pid: 36, cores: 2)


[wintermute]$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE             COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                               NAMES
91984e3f5c0e   flaskblog_flask   "sh"                     6 minutes ago    Up 5 minutes    8003/tcp                                            flask
86b1ee5367d7   flaskblog_nginx   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   13 minutes ago   Up 13 minutes   80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8083->8083/tcp, :::8083->8083/tcp   nginx


[wintermute]$ curl -s http://10.0.0.14:8083 | head -5
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
```

It works!

```
[wintermute]$ touch flaskblog/uwsgi.ini
```

...bummer that touch didn't reload uwsgi. Next I have to dig into why not. I do have a test container of a simpler project layout where this does work. But I'll save that quest for later .. perhaps.

For now, why is docker-compose up failing to start the app in the flask container?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the `volumes:` block in the Compose file.  (You can also safely delete `container_name:` and `expose:` and probably `cap_add:`, though these are less likely to cause problems.)

If you `docker-compose run flask sh`, or if you add an equivalent `docker run -v "$PWD/flaskblog:/app` option, you can see the effects of this.  The mount point is the `/app` directory in the container, so you're overwriting all of the code that you copied into the image.  However, you're overwriting it with the `flaskblog` subdirectory, so that gets "promoted" up to the top level and there's no longer a `/app/flaskblog` directory in the container filesystem.

You don't usually need to inject code into your container when the code is already in the image, and mounts like this can lead to inconsistent results.  I'd avoid this kind of `volumes:` mount if possible.